# What does 「父なる砂漠」mean?

Tags: words, quotes

There is a line in the 「この涙 星になれ」, which  is a song of ZARD (Sakai Izumi):

> 父なる砂漠 コイン投げて 明日を占おう

I don't understand the meaning of 「父なる砂漠」. It's quite strange to think of it as the desert that has been a father...

坂井泉水の大ファンなんです。今歌詞を整理しているので、理解出来ないところを問題にして、援助をお願いします。

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As sawa suggested, 母なる大地 (which literally means “the earth which is a mother”) is a fixed phrase to refer to Mother Earth, a common personification of the earth.  Just to clarify, 父なる砂漠 is not a common phrase, but it clearly builds on top of the phrase 母なる大地.  The phrase may be an invention by the writer of the song.

Interpretation of song lyrics is a delicate art, and I will not try to do it here.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ito San. If I knew 「母なる大地」, I would have no problem understanding 「父なる砂漠」. In my language, there is “大地母亲”, which is very similar to 「母なる大地」, but なる made me confused. I thought it meant "became".

Answer (score 5):

It does not say it has been a father. It says it is the father. Vast natural things like sea, earth, desert, universe, etc. are often metaphorically expressed as mother, father, the ancestors, or the homeland of human.

> - 母なる大地
>     'Earth, the mother of human'
> - 父なる砂漠
>     'Desert, the father of human'
> - 生命のふるさと、海
>     'The sea, the homeland of life'

I dont' think this is particular to Japanese.　But suddenly sticking in this phrase in this piece of lyrics does not make much sense. I don't think the quality of the lyrics is that high.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. In fact, before I gave out this question, I had searched 「父なる砂漠」 on google, and saw no other page containing it completely other than this piece of lyrics. So, I mention the lyrics just to explain the source of my question, not to ask for anyone else's appreciation for her lyrics. Although I think it is encouraging and marvellous.